# In MySQL on Linux, why does DESCRIBE ORDERS; command return an error saying "Table 'Records.orders' doesn't exists"?

Tags: mysql, database

I created a database named "Records" in MySQL within which I created a table named "old_records" having 5 columns. When I give the command:

```
USE Records;
SHOW TABLES;
```

it displays the table named "old_records" which is existing in the database, but after that when I type the command:

```
DESCRIBE ORDERS;
```

it gives the following error:

> ERROR 1146 (42S02) Table 'Records.orders' doesn't exists

I am very new to MySQL and not able to understand the cause of this error, please help.

Comment: You say you've created a table called "old_records". Why would you expect a table called "orders" to exist?

Comment: The error means that the table does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
DESCRIBE old_orders;
```

You've already said that the orders table does not exist, you cannot `DESCRIBE` something which doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got it. That was really an absurd question on my part i guess.